# Casting a float argument to unsigned when the function takes a signed int

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a large codebase which I need to sanitize and came across some code similar to the one below that GCC warns me about and that doesn't make any sense to me.

```
void SetValue(int32_t value);   // implementation not important

int main()
{
  //...

  float val = -10.0f;    // real value comes from a function, but can be negative 

  //...

  SetValue(uint32_t(val));  // huh?

  //...
}
```

Any reason to force cast to an `unsigned int` if the function takes a `signed int`?
This happens a few times throughout the codebase so it's not a single case.

Is it just a simple mistake or is there some trick that I'm missing?

EDIT: To be clear, the GCC sanitizer throws `runtime error: value -10 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned int'`.

Comment: Looks more like a mistake to me, probably just put there to hide a warning.

Comment: Elaborate with a [MCVE]- and  the exact waning message please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shown code, the cast appears to make no sense. Converting a floating point to an integer type in which the value is out of representable bounds has undefined behaviour. You don't want UB.

My guess: The cast is there to show explicitly that the float is converted to an integer, but the type is wrong by mistake.

Comment: Actually it is undefined behaviour (floating point conversions out of range are undefined). [conv.fpint]/1 .  So the code is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Using an explicit cast prevents many compilers from spitting out a warning about an implicit conversion and possible loss of data. it's not uncommon to put in casts to reduce the amount of compiler warnings: you're letting the compiler know that you're ok with the coversion.

In this case the value is being cast to an unsigned int then cast back to signed int. There is probably no reason at all to do that. My guess is that the function once took an unsigned int, and the cast was related to that (explicit cast to reduce the warnings), but later the function profile changed but the other part wasn't updated.